# Cannot install emonic c# plugin to Eclipse 3.7.2

Tags: c#, eclipse

I wanted to use the c# inside the Eclipse, but I get that error while trying to install. How to solve that problem.

Below: version of my Eclipse, source(put in the plugin manager) information after calculating dependencies.

```
Version: 3.7.2
Build id: M20120208-0800
```

---

```
 http://emonic.sourceforge.net/updatesite/internap/site.xml
```

---

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
org.emonic.debugger_feature.feature.group [0.0.2] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.
```

Comment: Having the same problem with Emonic on Eclipse Juno. Do you have a solution now? I had to uncheck the debugger but without the debugger, it would be pointless to use Eclipse for Mono.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but it *appears* that the `org.emonicdebugger` feature is exclusive to Linux:

[image: Screenshot from an installation where I experienced the same issue]

I was having the same problem. After I unchecked that feature from the download, the installation completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to download it four or five times and now I downloaded emonic successful with this link:

http://emonic.sourceforge.net/updatesite/nchc/site.xml (Tainan, Taiwan - Asia).

You have to uncheck the org.emonicdebugger!
I use Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)).
My operating system is Windows 7.